# Excel OR/IF/AND Statement Error

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am using the following excel formula to determine the value for a cell. I keep getting a "#VALUE!" error. Can anyone assist?

[image]

```
=OR(IF(AND(P3="NewEE",LEFT(O3,1)="D"),"DENTAL",IF(AND(P3="BEN2",LEFT(O3,1)="H"),"MEDICAL",
IF(AND(P3="BEN3",LEFT(O3,1)="V"),"VISION"))),IF(AND(Q3="NewEE",LEFT(O3,1)="D"),"DENTAL",
IF(AND(Q3="BEN2",LEFT(O3,1)="H"),"MEDICAL",IF(AND(Q3="BEN3",LEFT(O3,1)="V"),"VISION"))),
IF(AND(R3="NewEE",LEFT(O3,1)="D"),"DENTAL",IF(AND(R3="BEN2",LEFT(O3,1)="H"),"MEDICAL",
IF(AND(R3="BEN3",LEFT(O3,1)="V"),"VISION"))))
```

EXAMPLE 1:

[image]

EXAMPLE 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to nest all the ifs and do not use the OR():

```
=IF(AND(P2="NewEE",LEFT(O2,1)="D"),"DENTAL",IF(AND(P2="BEN2",LEFT(O2,1)="H"),"MEDICAL",IF(AND(P2="BEN3",LEFT(O2,1)="V"),"VISION",IF(AND(Q2="NewEE",LEFT(O2,1)="D"),"DENTAL",IF(AND(Q2="BEN2",LEFT(O2,1)="H"),"MEDICAL",IF(AND(Q2="BEN3",LEFT(O2,1)="V"),"VISION",IF(AND(R2="NewEE",LEFT(O2,1)="D"),"DENTAL",IF(AND(R2="BEN2",LEFT(O2,1)="H"),"MEDICAL",IF(AND(R2="BEN3",LEFT(O2,1)="V"),"VISION","")))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it still isn't coming out quite right, refer to Newly Edited question, Example 1 is how it came out when I removed the OR as you suggested. Example 2 is the result I need. How do I get to Example 2?

Comment: Did you use my formula? or yours with the OR removed, I refactored you formula a bit.

Comment: @designspeaks the formula you posted referred to row 3, I used that.  You posted my formula in row 2.  I have made the adjustment, see the edit.  Post it in S2 and copy down.

Comment: Thanks Scott, That one worked, however, it is giving me a few blank values with nothing in the cell? any ideas what may be causing that?

Comment: I solved my own problem, there was a double reference to BEN3, THANKS!

Comment: please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.